# adding item to a list then have list appear in a Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF app. It is not writing to a ComboBox properly and I am unsure why.

On the C drive there are number of folders labeled `Rameses-101`, `Rameses-102` and so on. In each folder there is a profile that is stored in a MDB Database. Until recently, we would rename the active "Rameses" folder to change profiles and perform work on it.

[image: Current WPF Form]

So above is part of my form and the installed profile selection combobox lists all the folders that start with `Rameses-*` and then lists them. People complained that the folders naming convention sucks, and would like something easier. So Instead of using the folder names, I want to be able to list the Name stored in the database inside each folder, and have the dropdown box list those instead of the folder names.

I have gotten to the point where I can get it to display a single folders profile name but that's it. Also I was able to get it to list all the names, however they were on one line and mashed together in the combobox.

Question is what am I doing wrong in the code. Not sure exactly where the problem is! Either I am not adding items to the datalist properly or not closing the loop properly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
string directory = @"C:\";
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory, "Rameses-*");
List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
foreach (string foldername in folders)
{
    //var myDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
    using (var conection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=" + foldername + "\\Program\\Ramdata.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****"))
    {
        conection.Open();
        var query = "Select u_company From t_user";
        var command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conection);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //profselect.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            dataList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
        conection.Close();
    }
    profselect.DataSource = dataList;
    profselect.SelectedText = dataList.Last();
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Shouldn't the last two statements `profselect.DataSource = dataList;` and `profselect.SelectedText = dataList.Last();` go outside the for loop block? Apparently, DataSource is overwritten in each loop iteration..

Comment: that did it raven. everything seems to be working now. silly me I thought they were out of the loop on first glance. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data-binding should go outside the loop block.

```
foreach(...)
{
    ...
}
profselect.DataSource = dataList;
profselect.SelectedText = dataList.Last();
```

Glad to hear that it worked for you! 8-)

Comment: see now the trick comes in referencing the folder it was found in. so when the profile is selected which will be the name in the database, if they hit the switch button then it will need to know the corresponding folder and then perform the process....

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I am going to assume this question is mis-tagged as WPF and is really about winforms in which case my answer doesn't make sense

profselect.ItemsSource = datalist;

(not DataSource)
and indeed it probably should be outside the loop

Comment: Hang on. How does DataSource even compile in WPF? This must be winforms not WPF?